# AzureAD last login powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get last user login in azure, but only find that information over log and only have last 60 days.

> `get-azaduser` only give the names and accounts, how can I get all details about all accounts.

Thanks

I would like to have all details about all account in my domain, and also know last usage/login for all.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

To fetch the **Azure AD User details and the Last login time** I used the below PowerShell script:

```
Connect-AzureAD

$users = Get-AzureADUser -All $true

foreach ($user in $users) {
    $loginLogs = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$($user.UserPrincipalName)'"
    $lastLoginTime = $loginLogs.CreatedDateTime
    $user | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "LastLoginTime" -NotePropertyValue $lastLoginTime
}
$users | Select-Object DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, ObjectId, LastLoginTime
```

The Last login time of all the Users is displayed like below:

[image]

Comment: `Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs` appears to be in preview.